# How to return two variables from promise DataLoader?

Tags: python, promise, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have a python promise DataLoader object and it is called from GraphQL query as below.

The Loader class;

```
class ExampleLoader(DataLoader):
    def batch_load_fn(self, _):
        data = get_data()
        return Promise.resolve([data])

example_loader = ExampleLoader()
```

The GraphQL query;

```
def resolve_data(self, info, **kwargs):
    return example_loader.load('data').then(lambda data: data.demands[getattr(self, 'material_number')])
```

**This works fine.**

However, I need to return two variables from the `get_data` function, and also I need to return those variables from Loader to GraphQL query. So I tried the following solution.

```
class ExampleLoader(DataLoader):
    def batch_load_fn(self, _):
        data, error_dict = get_data()
        return Promise.resolve([data]), error_dict

example_loader = ExampleLoader()
```

```
def resolve_data(self, info, **kwargs):
    data, error_dict = example_loader.load('data')
    return data.then(lambda data: data.demands[getattr(self, 'material_number')])
```

But I'm getting `There is no current event loop in thread` error. How can I get those two variables in my GraphQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [asyncio Dataloaders](https://github.com/syrusakbary/aiodataloader) instead of Promise based dataloaders as promises were deprecated in graphene V3 check [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/1390). You will face a lot of issues in the future upon upgrading.